Why doesnt Majin Buu have pointy ears if he's a demon?
In Dragon Ball Daima they mentioned all inhabitants from the Demon Realm have pointy ears. But Majin Buu is a demon from there and he doesnt have pointy ears, but "Freezer-like" ears.
Why doesnt Majin Buu have pointy ears if he's a demon?

Well, he's an artificial being, so there doesn't seem to be any reason for his anatomical features to be the same as everybody else's. In point of fact, this is usually the explanation for him having peculiar anatomical features.
